# If array contains value works only when the next array has a value

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following PHP Script. Its workes fine, when Array[5] has a value and Array[4] is = "test", but when Array[5] has no value it's dont work.

```
// get file
$file = "latest.log";

// test if file exists
 if(!file_exists($file)) {
  die("file not found");
}


while(TRUE) {

    // open file
    $file = escapeshellarg($file);
    $file_handle = `tail -n 1 $file`;


    # get line & convert to array
    $array = explode(' ', $file_handle);
```

This works fine, when I execute this i get the following Array:

> Array (
>
> ```
> [0] => [11:14:59]
> [1] => [Server
> [2] => thread/INFO]:
> [3] => KaiAlexander
> [4] => test
> ```
>
> )

```
          $player_name = str_replace("<", "", $array[3]);
          $player_name = str_replace(">", "", $player_name);
          $array[3] = $player_name;


            echo('Text: ' . $array[4] ." von " . $player_name);

                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($array);
                echo "</pre>"; //Prints the array on top


            if ($array[4] == "test") {
                echo("works");
            } else {
                echo($array[4]);
                //Echo the correct value "test"!
            }
        }
```

I don't understand the mistake... With `in_array` it's also do the same.

Comment: You values has newlines or spaces definitely. Use `trim` to remove them.

Comment: Thank you! Now its work.